# c# NaN comparison differences between Equals() and ==

Tags: c#, equals, nan

Check this out :

```
    var a = Double.NaN;

    Console.WriteLine(a == a);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints "False"

```
    var a = Double.NaN;

    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(a));
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints "True"!

Why it prints "True"? Due to floating point numbers specification, value that is NaN is not equal to itself! So it seems that Equals() method is implemented wrong...
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you give example where result comes to be different.

Comment: I think this question was improperly closed because it's asking about the difference between == and Equals, not about why == returns true.  The questioner is already clear on why == returns false, but goes on to ask why Equals returns true, which is a different question.

Comment: Why It's closed? This question is about "Why Equals() in .NET does not follow floating-point numbers specification", not about things covered in linked questions..

Comment: It was closed because some people are idiots ... this question has nothing to do with the supposed duplicate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found an article addressing your question: [.NET Security Blog: Why == and the Equals Method Return Different Results for Floating Point Values](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/07/19/187792.aspx)

> According to IEC 60559:1989, two
>   floating point numbers with values of
>   NaN are never equal.  However,
>   according to the specification for the
>   System.Object::Equals method, it's
>   desirable to override this method to
>   provide value equality semantics. 
>   [...]
>
> So now we have two conflicting ideas
>   of what Equals should mean. 
>   Object::Equals says that the BCL value
>   types should override to provide value
>   equality, and IEC 60559 says that NaN
>   does not equal NaN.  Partition I of
>   the ECMA spec provides resolution for
>   this conflict by making a note about
>   this specific case in section 8.2.5.2 [below]

---

**Update:**  The full text of section 8.2.5 from [the CLI spec (ECMA-335)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf) sheds some more light on this.  I've copied the relevant bits here:

> ## 8.2.5 Identity and equality of values
>
> There are two binary operators defined
>   on all pairs of values: *identity* and
>   *equality*. They return a Boolean result, and are mathematical
>   *equivalence operators*; that is, they are:
>
> - Reflexive – `a op a` is true.
> - Symmetric – `a op b` is true if and only if `b op a` is true.
> - Transitive – if `a op b` is true and `b op c` is true, then `a op c` is
>     true.
>
> In addition, while identity always
>   implies equality, the reverse is not
>   true. [...]
>
> ### 8.2.5.1 Identity
>
> The identity operator is defined by the CTS as follows.
>
> - If the values have different exact types, then they are not identical.
> - Otherwise, if their exact type is a value type, then they are identical if
>     and only if the bit sequences of the
>     values are the same, bit by bit.
> - Otherwise, if their exact type is a reference type, then they are
>     identical if and only if the locations
>     of the values are the same.
>
> Identity is implemented on `System.Object` via the `ReferenceEquals` method.
>
> ### 8.2.5.2 Equality
>
> For value types, the equality operator
>   is part of the definition of the exact
>   type. Definitions of equality should
>   obey the following rules:
>
> - Equality should be an equivalence operator, as defined above.
> - Identity should imply equality, as stated earlier.
> - If either (or both) operand is a boxed value, [...]
>
> Equality is implemented on
>   `System.Object` via the `Equals`
>   method.
>
> [*Note*: Although two floating point
>   NaNs are defined by IEC 60559:1989 to
>   always compare as unequal, the
>   contract for System.Object.Equals
>   requires that overrides must satisfy
>   the requirements for an equivalence
>   operator. Therefore,
>   `System.Double.Equals` and
>   `System.Single.Equals` return True
>   when comparing two NaNs, while the
>   equality operator returns False in
>   that case, as required by the IEC
>   standard. *end note*]

The above does not specify the properties of the `==` operator at all (except for the final note); it is primarily defining the behavior of `ReferenceEquals` and `Equals`. For the behavior of the `==` operator, [the C# language spec (ECMA-334)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) (section 14.9.2) is clear about how to treat NaN values:

> If either operand [to `operator ==`] is NaN, the result is false

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I actually understand the reasoning here. The article talks about conflicts between the ECMA spec and the IEEE spec because the former says that `Object.Equals` should provide value equality semantics while the latter says that `double.NaN` is not equal to itself. Where is the conflict here? Wouldn't "the requirements for an equivalence operator" for a type based on an IEEE spec be the same as those of equality as defined in the IEEE spec? I just don't really get this explanation.

Comment: @Dan - you're right; it wasn't really a complete answer.  Please see if my update above clears things up.

Comment: I think the part about *identity* for value types clears it up for me: "they are identical if and only **if the bit sequences of the values are the same**, bit by bit"—clearly this will be the case for two `double.NaN` values (this along with "Identity should imply equality"). Nice reference.

Comment: @DanTao Look at the definition of the Reflexive property of an equivalence operator. It is impossible to define an equivalence operator, and thus an equality operator, over any set containing NaN ... regardless of whether equality is defined to be bit-by-bit equivalence. And bit-by-bit equivalence only applies to identity, not equality, and identity is only required for ReferenceEquals.

Answer (score 9):

`Equals` is made for things like hashtables. And thus it contract requires that `a.Equals(a)`.

MSDN states:

> The following statements must be true for all implementations of the Equals method. In the list, x, y, and z represent object references that are not null.
>
> x.Equals(x) returns true, except in cases that involve floating-point types. See IEC 60559:1989, Binary Floating-point Arithmetic for Microprocessor Systems.
>
> x.Equals(y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x).
>
> x.Equals(y) returns true if both x and y are NaN.
>
> If (x.Equals(y) && y.Equals(z)) returns true, then x.Equals(z) returns true.
>
> Successive calls to x.Equals(y) return the same value as long as the objects referenced by x and y are not modified.
>
> x.Equals(null) returns false.
>
> See GetHashCode for additional required behaviors pertaining to the Equals method.

What I find strange is that it states "x.Equals(x) returns true, except in cases that involve floating-point types. See IEC 60559:1989, Binary Floating-point Arithmetic for Microprocessor Systems." but at the same time requires that NaN equals NaN. So why did they put that exception in? Because of different NaNs?

In a similar way when using an `IComparer<double>` the floating-point standard must be violated too. Since `IComparer` requires a consistent total ordering.

Comment: The IEEE NaN is a very strange animal indeed. It's occurrence in data typically indicates that something very odd is happening, and that things have gone badly wrong. Pretend it doesn't exist. Ignore that man behind the curtain.

Comment: IEEE floating points have many quirks. A multitude of different NaNs, the properties of the infinities, two different zeros, denorms,... And you can't just ignore them because those quirks might break some assumptions other code makes.

Comment: One reason for the first sentence is because of extended precision. In the x86 processor familly floating point (double) values still in the floating point registers have 80 bits, while those values in memory are rounded down to 64 bits. Compilers are free to move values between memory and registers at any time, and use the full extended precision for comparison. The result is that it is not guaranteed that `x==x` for a floating point `x`, even if `x` is not `NaN`! This frequently trips up people who think they understand floating point.

Answer (score 6):

If I were to venture a guess, it might be that this is to support the use of `double` values as keys in a dictionary.

If `x.Equals(y)` returned `false` for `x = double.NaN` and `y = double.NaN`, then you could have code like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<double, string>();

double x = double.NaN;

dict.Add(x, "These");
dict.Add(x, "have");
dict.Add(x, "duplicate");
dict.Add(x, "keys!");
```

I think the majority of developers would find this behavior rather unintuitive. **But even *more* counterintuitive would be this:**

```
// This would output false!
Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(x));
```

Basically, with an implementation of `Equals` that **never** returns `true` for a certain value, what you would have is a type capable of providing keys with the following bizarre behavior:

- Could be added an unlimited number of times to a dictionary
- Could *not* be detected using `ContainsKey`, and therefore...
- Could never be removed using `Remove`

Remember that `Equals` is very closely related to `GetHashCode` for this very reason (the C# compiler even warns you if you've overridden one without the other)—a big part of why they're there in the first place is to facilitate the use of types as hash table keys.

Like I said, it's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

While you're correct that `NaN == NaN` is false, `double.Equals` specially handles `NaN` differently, in a way that `NaN.Equals(NaN)` is true.  Here's the .NET 4 implementation of the method from reflector:

```
public bool Equals(double obj)
{
    return ((obj == this) || (IsNaN(obj) && IsNaN(this)));
}
```