# Are there any scenarios in which (i != i) will be evaluated to true?

Tags: java

I'm just beginning to wrap my head around `.equals()` vs `==` , Java's pass-by-copy vs pass-by-reference, etc. And I was wondering if there would ever be a scenario in Java where this would be run infinitely:

```
while (i != i) {
    // infinite loop
}
```

I have some ideas regarding String objects, Array objects, etc, but can't quite get anything to work. Thanks.

Comment: When `i` is the floating-point `NaN` value.

Comment: it's only `pass by value`..there is nothing as `pass by copy` or `pass by reference` in java

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933769/c-sharp-nan-comparison-differences-between-equals-and

Comment: @TomHatwin Try it.  NaN != NaN is true.

Comment: @DMoses Wrong language.  He was asking about Java, not CSharp.

Comment: if i is shared between threads and no proper synchronization is used this could also evaluate to true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while (Double.NaN != Double.NaN)
```

I believe this is the "[bride of looper](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/cse4051/java-puzzlers/4-loopy-puzzlers/puzzle-29/BrideOfLooper-java.html)" puzzle in the `Java Puzzlers` book.

See [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.21.1) for reference:

> Floating-point equality testing is performed in accordance with the rules of the IEEE 754 standard:
>
> If either operand is NaN, then the result of == is false but the
>   result of != is true. Indeed, the test x!=x is true if and only if the
>   value of x is NaN. (The methods Float.isNaN and Double.isNaN may also
>   be used to test whether a value is NaN.)

Comment: Ah, well that's interesting. Another tidbit of obscure standards specifications to add to my brain :)