# Why does Microsoft's complex number implementation prefer strict comparisons?

Tags: c#, .net

I know that floating point numbers are best compared within a certain interval. But why does Microsoft's [complex number implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/Complex.cs) use strict comparisons for operator `==`?

Source code:

```
public static bool operator ==(Complex left, Complex right) 
{
    return ((left.m_real == right.m_real) && (left.m_imaginary == right.m_imaginary));
}
```

My attempt:

```
public static bool operator ==(Complex left, Complex right) 
{
    return ((Math.Abs(left.m_real - right.m_real) < EPS) && 
            (Math.Abs(left.m_imaginary - right.m_imaginary) < EPS));
}
```

Comment: You question makes it sound like the MS compiler is special. It likely does so because this is what every other compiler on the planet does that I have ever seen.

Comment: Another possible approach `(right - left).Abs() < EPS`.

Comment: It would be more surprising to me if the `==` operator considered two values which are not exactly the same to be the same. Whoever uses the complex number type must make the decision whether using equality or equality-within-a-certain-delta is more suitable, just like they would for `float`, `double`, `decimal`, etc.

Comment: I doubt the person who made that decision is around here to answer your question. The rest of us can offer only opinions. That said, it is completely standard in the context of .NET for `==` to be a strict value-equality comparison. Though, ironically, `double` does have one exception to this rule (and so any type based on `double` would as well): comparisons between `NaN` always have a result of `false`, even for two binary-identical values. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933769/c-sharp-nan-comparison-differences-between-equals-and

Comment: Note that "equal with tolerance" has the odd property that you can end up with x==y, y==z, but x != z.